# Is it possible to obtain the displayable area, width and height of current buffer in Vim?

Tags: vimscript, buffers, split

I know Vim provides functions to display window's dimensions. But does it also
provide ways for me to know current buffer/split's dimensions? Like how many lines
and columns in displable area?

Currently all I can find online is the information on how to change the split
width and height rather than obtaining the current dimension. But I don't need
to change the split size, only need to know its size information to
organize some material in the buffer.

---

Edit: As indicated by @Tommy A in his comment, the reason I have this question
is that I misunderstood of the terminology. To quote him:

> A window is a viewport for a buffer. "Split" is just a verb in Vim. I think
>   you might be mixing up the terminology for windows and buffers. Soft wrapping
>   occurs at winwidth(0) and it's also the the total number of characters that
>   can be displayed horizontally. Hard wrapping occurs at &textwidth.

Hence what I want to do is to show the window dimension, by `winwidth(0)` and
`winheight(0)`.

Also, as mentioned in Question [Get Usable Window Width in Vim
Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315925/get-usable-window-width-in-vim-script/26318602#26318602),
`winwidth(0)` is usually larger than the usable width of the window for the
content. To obtain the correct size information, please refer to the answer in
that question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26318602/789222

Comment: The answer is right in the question you linked to!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are the different ways (that I know of) to get dimensional information from Vim.

### Vim

`&columns` and `&lines` will give you the total width and height of the screen Vim is displayed in.  These can be changed at runtime, but it's not recommended.

`&cmdheight` will give you the height of the command line.

### Windows

`winwidth(0)` and `winheight(0)` will give you the dimensions for the current window.  It includes the width of the gutter columns, but not the window separator.

If you wanted to get the size as a ratio, you would need to turn one of the values into a float:

```
let width_ratio = winwidth(0) / str2float(&columns)
let height_ratio = winheight(0) / str2float(&lines)
```

### Buffers

If you want the total number of lines in a buffer:

```
let total_lines = line('$')
```

If you want the number of *visible* lines in a buffer:

```
let visible_lines = line('w$') - line('w0')
```

`w$` is the bottom line and `w0` is the top line.

To get the maximum column from the buffer, you could use:

```
function! BufferWidth() abort
  let view = winsaveview()
  let max_col = 0
  g/^/let max_col=max([max_col, col('$') - 1])
  call histdel('search', -1)
  let @/ = histget('search', -1)
  call winrestview(view)
  return max_col
endfunction
```

The `:global` command is used to get the last column in every line and keep the highest value.  The rest of the function saves/restores the state since `:global` moves the cursor and changes the search history.

Comment: I see. So maybe there is no direct way to get it. Not that I can't find one... Thanks for your complete answer. I'll wait a while to see if there really no one know of any direct method or if it really doesn't exist before accepting your answer. :)

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to do? From your description, it sounds like `winwidth()` and `winheight()` are what you're looking for.

Comment: I want to know how many character a split/buffer can display before soft wrapping or getting beyong visible range. Also how many lines it can display in its display range. Now that taking a closer look, even your `BufferWidth` doesn't really do the first part...

Comment: A window is a viewport for a buffer.  "Split" is just a verb in Vim.  I think you might be mixing up the terminology for windows and buffers.  Soft wrapping occurs at `winwidth(0)` and it's also the the total number of characters that can be displayed horizontally.  Hard wrapping occurs at `&textwidth`.

Comment: I see, `winwidth(0)` appears to be what I want... Strange it's value is a few character longer than the number of columns able to contain in the line... Does `line number` occupy the `winwidth(0)`?

Comment: Oh strange, it *does* include the line column and sign column.

Comment: It can be excluded manually, as the answer referred to in my edit of question. :)